# Runnable in Handler not run when posted from inside a push notification IntentService

Tags: android, push-notification, intentservice, android-handler

In my app when I receive a push notification I want to fire a web request to the server to update some data. This is my implementation of `IntentService.onHandleIntent()`, which is called when I receive a push:

```
@Override protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

    final NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    final NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
    // ... notification setup
    notificationManager.notify(Integer.parseInt(intent.getStringExtra("id")), notificationBuilder.build());

    // Web request to the server to update data
    syncData(this);

    // Release the wake lock provided by the WakefulBroadcastReceiver.
    PushNotificationsReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);

}

public static void syncData(final Context content) {
    new Handler().post(new Runnable() {
        @Override public void run() {
            // ... my web request
        }
    });
}
```

There's no reason in wrapping the request in a Runnable run by an Handler, but the fact is that the runnable is not run. I even checked the return value of `post()`, and it's `true`. If I call `syncData()` from inside an activity, or a fragment, etc, it works as expected, but not in this `IntentService`. **Why is that?**

If do this instead, everything works correctly:

```
public static void syncData(final Context content) {
    // ... my web request
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In an `IntentService`, `onHandleIntent()` will be called on a separate thread created by the `IntentService`. So when you call `new Handler()`, a handler instance will be created for that new thread. When you post a runnable using that handler, it will be posted on the new thread's handler and thread's `onHandleMessage` will be called which is implemented by `IntentService` and it is ignored.

If you modify the above code as below it will work

```
public static void syncData(final Context content) {
new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
    @Override public void run() {
        // ... my web request
    }
});
}
```

but in the above `Runable` will be called on main thread where you should not perform network operation

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation. It's clear now. Thank you for the workaround too, but as you said I cannot do network there. So I'll get rid of the handler as I already shown, anyway I learned something new in the process :)